# How do I edit grub.cfg to always dump me at the grub prompt?

Tags: grub

I have a custom grub.cfg.  What I want is for grub to parse that grub.cfg, and then immediately leave me at the grub prompt:

```
grub>
```

so that I can type in a command that I want.

I know that I can press "c" from a menu to get that prompt, but I don't want to do that.  I don't want a menu, and I don't want to have to press "c" to get the prompt.  Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to be dumped at the grub prompt?

Comment: Sounds like you don't want a `grub.cfg` then. The `grub.cfg` is meant to automate what grub does. If you don't want grub to do anything automatically, try moving your `grub.cfg`.

Comment: I want to manually load the kernel and boot with specific kernel parameters.

I can't get rid of grub.cfg because I'm booting grub.  It won't do anything if grub.cfg is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, kinda.  I had to fake it with the "read" command:

```
while true
do
    echo -n "grub> "
    read COMMAND
    echo ""
    if [ "$COMMAND" = "exit" ]
    then
            exit
    fi
    $COMMAND
done
```